# The most basic IPC between Python and C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, windows, ipc

I'm writing a DLL (Windows, MS VS 17) in C++ which requires to call a Python script at some point - it should read a json-encoded string, process it and give back the json-encoded result. There is no need for asynchronous mode or "speed of light", but I need more or less fast response - i. e. within 1-5 seconds max. Here are the approaches I considered and the comments:

1. **Pass the string as a command line argument**. This is, obviously, not the best choice - let alone string length limit.
2. **Use a temporary file**. It will be the best to avoid such practice in my case, because although I need to run the Python-part generally *once* per launch, the number of launches may be quite big.
3. **Use a TCP/IP socket (for `localhost`) / pipe**. Both seem to be an overkill for such a task - I do not have a continuous flow of data which changes constantly. Besides, in Windows it might be a pain.
4. **Use shared memory**. Shared memory would be a nice option but I couldn't find a way to use the same segment both in C++ and Python.
5. **Embed Python part into C++**. I have 2 concerns here: a) Python env should be installed on the target machine, shouldn't it? b) A python script has an `import`, which imports a package, installed from pip and, unfortunately, I cannot avoid it. Is there a proper way to work with imports when embedding?

Is there a simple way to interoperate between C++ and Python in my case?

Comment: Regarding shared memory - you could use a named shared memory segment and pass the name to the Python script. Not sure what Python API is for shared memory. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're targeting Windows, option (2) is the best, but use a temporary file  `CreateFile(...FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY)`. That's effectively shared memory (at the OS level, both are managed by the Virtual Memory Manager) but you get file semantics.

Comment: Thanks, MSalters! How can I access it from Python? Just via its standard I/O functions?

Comment: @JamesFrezz: Yes. Python asks the OS, and the OS has the file in RAM cache because the C++ code told the OS that it was a temporary file. So the OS immediately gives Python the result.

Comment: I checked upon this approach and noticed that a zero-length file is getting created in the current directory - not a big deal, but it's slightly irritating. So I decided to go for shared memory, using the @Andrey's advice. Just in case, if someone stumbles upon an import error when working with shared memory - consider upgrading to Python 3.8.

Comment: @JamesFrezz: Well, it depends on _where_ you create it. It has file semantics, after all, which includes a file path. There's `GetTempPath`, which may give a more appropriate path.